# Trying to pull saved input from local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, local-storage

I'm having trouble saving input text into local storage and retrieving it with JS. This is a scheduler application and I have multiple input boxes organized by hour and user should be able to input their plan into the text box and save it, and it should be retrieved on page reload.
Here is my JS:

```
// Add input to local storage-------------------------------------------------------//

const button = document.querySelector('.saveBtn');
const hours = ['9', '10' , '11', '12' , '13', '14', '15', '16', '17'];


function savePlan() {
    for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        // TEST: console.log(hours[i]);
        let input11 = document.getElementById('red').value;
        console.log(input11);
    };
    localStorage.setItem('plan', hours[i].value);
    // console.log(plan);
    
};

button.addEventListener('click', savePlan());

// Retrieves plan from local Storage-----------------------------------------------//
function getPlan() {
    return localStorage.getItem('plan');
};

getPlan();
```

and here is part of my HTML: ( I have multiple boxes like this for hours 0900-1700)

```
 <tr class="row" id="11">
            <th scope="time" id="hour11"class="time">11:00</th>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" id="h11input"></td>
            <td class="btnContainer">
              <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row" id="12">
            <th scope="time" id="hour12" class="time">12:00</th>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" id="h12input"></td>
            <td class="btnContainer">
              <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to make things a string to place them into localstorage.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You execute `getPlan()` but there is nothing to handle the return value. Than you trying set "plan" from outside of `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code asks to store the object hours[i].value into the local storage key 'plan' it will fail for two reasons:

1. The "i" variable is scoped to the for loop above it; the loop is over, and "i" will be undefined.

```
localStorage.setItem('plan', hours[i]); // will write 'undefined' to local storage
```

2. The "hours" array is an array of strings. There is no "value" property on a string; to confirm this, you can try to type "Hello, world!".value into your Chrome dev tools. You can store 'undefined' into local storage, but what you can't do is pass access an undefined "value" property (.value) on an undefined value (hours[i]) into localStorage.setItem() - this will throw a TypeError.

```
localStorage.setItem('plan', hours[i].value); // will throw a TypeError because it can't read a 'value' property of undefined
```

I'm not super clear on what you're trying to do here, but some contrived code that may be closer to the mark might look like [this](https://codepen.io/brendanbond/pen/BaRJyed).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still troubleshooting but good advice for sure, and has led me to experiment with a couple different approaches. I'm making a day planner application that has textbox inputs for each hour of the work day (0900-1700) with a save button. When the save button is pressed, whatever is typed into that textbox will be saved to local storage and automatically retrieved when page refreshed. Having issues with connecting the individual input textboxes into this so that whatever is typed in them will be saved.

Comment: @hannahatl I just updated the answer with a link to a super quick and dirty codepen - hopefully that'll shed some light on what you're trying to do

Comment: Wow thank you so much for putting all that together! It definitely is helping. I've implemented the code you suggested and it doesn't quite work yet, just saves an empty array into local storage so hopefully I can troubleshoot from here to figure it out

Comment: It works, but only with the save all button and not the individual ones. Still trying to make it work with the individual ones too. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @hannahstl remember that in that code, the plan takes precedence over the individual blocks - that was just an implementation detail; try clearing the plan and then saving an individual block, and then try to follow the path that the code takes when you load, when you click save item, and when you click save plan. Good luck!